# Failed to compile entry-point @angular/material/select

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am getting an error when I try to compile my Angular 9 project.

This is the error I get when I run ng serve:

```
ERROR in Failed to compile entry-point @angular/material/select (es2015 as esm2015) due to compilation errors:
node_modules/@angular/material/fesm2015/select.js:2036:26 - error NG1010: Value at position 0 in the NgModule.exports of MatSelectModule is not a reference: [object Object]

2036                 exports: [
                              ~
2037                     CdkScrollableModule,
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 ... 
2042                     MatCommonModule
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2043                 ],
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-calendars": "^18.1.44",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.38",
    "alertifyjs": "^1.13.1",
    "angular-mat-datepicker": "0.0.2",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.21",
    "angularx-qrcode": "^2.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "material-steppers": "^2.0.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.900.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was resolved when I deleted package-lock.json